# How To Check Database Field is NULL

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

I have this code snippet that making a call to a database table, where I was to perform some actions, like allocate a room, is the field `HostelName` is NULL.

But after trying many methods turns out the NULL fields are not being truly observed in my code and the execution always enters the first IF statement even though the field is NULL. Is there really a way to check if a field is NULL and perform some actions accordingly? Am a bit of a novice in Qt and Database.

**Note:**

MatricNo is the primary key. Which obviously the SELECT statement can return just one record(I guess).

```
qry.prepare("SELECT * from student where matricno='"+matric+"' and HostelName IS NULL");
qry.exec();
QSqlRecord rec = qry.record();
if(rec.isNull("HostelName"))
{
    qry.prepare("UPDATE student set HostelName='"+hostelName+"',RoomNo='"+roomNo+"' where MatricNo='"+matric+"'");
    if(qry.exec())
    {
        qry.prepare("UPDATE Rooms set OccupantsNo=OccupantsNo-1 where HostelName='"+hostelName+"' and roomID='"+roomNo+"'");
        if(qry.exec())
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),tr("Student Room Allocated"));
        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),qry.lastError().text());
    }
}
else
{
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error"),"Cant Allocate Room: \nStudent Room Already Alloted\nTo Re-Allocate, Go to Edit Student Details");//qry.lastError().text());
}
```

Comment: you can provide a [mcve], also if the database is sqlite the .db file

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following problems in your code:

First: your `rec` is just null! you are assigning `QSqlRecord rec` immediately after `qry.exec()` .. where result is currently located **before the first record** , you have to position query to first record first [QSqlQuery::next()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#next)
 .. at least this is needed to get your code work.

```
qry.exec();
qry.next();
QSqlRecord rec = qry.record();
```

Second: your sql statement have already selected based on `HostelName IS NULL` 
 but you are checking the result for `rec.isNull("HostelName")` ... this is just useless and needless, you probably want  `rec.isNull("RoomNo")` or something else or nothing! but after your select statement the record value of `HostelName` is always `NULL`.